# How to set styles for <swiper-slide> when using injectStyles in Swiper Element (WebComponent)?

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm using [Swiper Element (WebComponent)](https://swiperjs.com/element) and I'm trying to adjust the styles of each slide. I'm using `injectStyles` for this purpose, which works fine for most parts:

```
export const PROJECT_SWIPER_OPTIONS: SwiperOptions = {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: false,
  grabCursor: true,
  navigation: true,
  injectStyles: [`
    :host {
      height: 100%;
    }

    :host .swiper-wrapper {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }

    :host .swiper-slide {
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
  `],
};
```

The styles for `:host` and `:host .swiper-wrapper` are applied correctly. Unfortunately the styles for `:host .swiper-slide` are ignored. I also tried `:host .slide`, `:host swiper-slide` but it won't work either.

It seems that the styles aren't applied since the `<swiper-slide>` elements are slotted into the shadow element.

Any idea how to style the elements?

Currently I'm using this in my Angular project:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  swiper-slide {
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
}
```

Which works, but I do have styles in the Swiper config and the componentn SCSS now. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Lo has solucionado?, tengo el mismo problema en react

Comment: @CamiloVasquez I solved it temporarily by adding styles to the `swiper-slide`-element like shown in the question. The `:host ::ng-deep { }`-selector can be omitted and is Angular specific. So it should work in React also.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your stylesheet in case you are using the [Swiper Element (WebComponent)](https://swiperjs.com/element). Look at the html and the parts that you can use, e.g. `::part(pagination)` for the Pagination module.

```
swiper-container {
    --swiper-theme-color: #ababab;
    --swiper-navigation-size: 22px;
    --swiper-navigation-color: #e1e1e1;
    --swiper-navigation-top-offset: 10px;
    --swiper-navigation-sides-offset: 10px;
    --swiper-pagination-color: #92a4ae;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-border-radius: 6px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap: 4px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-vertical-gap: 4px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-size: 6px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-width: 6px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-height: 6px;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity: 1;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: #254a5d;
    --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity: 1;
    --swiper-pagination-bottom: 0rem;
    --swiper-preloader-color: var(--swiper-theme-color);
}

swiper-container {
    /* styles */
}

swiper-container::part(bullet) {
    /* styles */
}

swiper-container::part(bullet-active) {
    /* styles */
}

swiper-container::part(pagination) {
    /* styles */
}

swiper-container::part(container) {
    /* styles */
}

swiper-container::part(button-prev),
swiper-container::part(button-next) {
    /* styles */
}
```